# Dropwizard: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire the logger context

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j, dropwizard

I have a project which is having multiple modules within it. One of the module, say "main", is having my service class, "MyService.class". Dropwizard has a jar - dropwizard-core. I want this jar in more than one module, so I was thinking of keeping its dependency in parent POM. By doing that, while running my dropwizard service file, I am encountering an exception as follows:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.12/slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/username/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.<br>
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]<br><br>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire the logger context
                at io.dropwizard.logging.LoggingUtil.getLoggerContext(LoggingUtil.java:46)
                at io.dropwizard.logging.BootstrapLogging.bootstrap(BootstrapLogging.java:45)
                at io.dropwizard.logging.BootstrapLogging.bootstrap(BootstrapLogging.java:34)
                at io.dropwizard.Application.<init>(Application.java:24)
                at my.project.package.MyService.<init>(MyService.java:31)
                at my.project.package.MyService.main(MyService.java:38)
```

This project runs perfectly fine if I put the dependency in the POM of "main" module.

Dropwizard is binding with wrong logger and that is the reason behind this exception. But this binding happens in the background and I have no control over it.

I am also sharing the dependency tree for both the scenarios.

**Case 1 : When dropwizard-core is in child POM (main module) :**

```
my.groupId.myProject:myProject-main:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT<br>
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk7:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-configuration:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-logging:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile<br><br>
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-servlets:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-lifecycle:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.6.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid:jetty-setuid-java:jar:1.0.3:compile<br>
[INFO] +- de.thomaskrille:dropwizard-template-config:jar:1.1.0:compile<br>
[INFO] +- my.groupId.myProject:myProject-module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile<br>
[INFO] +- my.groupId.myProject:myProject-module2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile<br>
[INFO] +- my.groupId.myProject:myProject-module3:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:0.9.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  \- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:jar:0.9.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile<br>
[INFO] |     +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-httpclient:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test<br>
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test<br>
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test<br>
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test<br>
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test<br>

**Case 2 : When dropwizard-core is in parent POM :**

 my.groupId.myProject:myProject-main:jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT<br>
[INFO] +- de.thomaskrille:dropwizard-template-config:jar:1.1.0:compile<br>
[INFO] +- my.groupId.myProject:myProject-module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile<br>
[INFO] +- my.groupId.myProject:myProject-module2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile<br>
[INFO] +- my.groupId.myProject:myProject-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:0.9.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  \- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:jar:0.9.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile<br>
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile<br>
[INFO] |     +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-httpclient:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk7:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-configuration:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-logging:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.3:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.1:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-servlets:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.13.v20150730:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-lifecycle:jar:0.9.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2:compile<br>
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.6.0:compile<br>
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid:jetty-setuid-java:jar:1.0.3:compile<br>
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test<br>
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test<br>
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test<br>
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test<br>
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test<br>
```

If anyone could come up with a possible reasoning, it would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get around this. I am facing a similar exception

Comment: Me too, but OP hasn't logged in for about a year.  Am I going to have to offer a bounty?

Comment: See if this is of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782932/with-the-shaded-jar-from-dropwizard-i-got-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bi/49924368#49924368

Comment: is that using something like Java 9 modules? Because if it's typical maven/java, then the place where you set the dependency shouldn't have any impact: everything is in the same classpath...
Or are you using some kind of special way of building the classpath? The whole pom would be helpful I think

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is that you have two different slf4j implementations (aka bindings) in your classpath and this shouldn't be the case.

When this happens, the first one (in order of appearance in the classpath) is used by slf4j. Then dropwizard `LoggingUtil` tries to retrieve the actual `ILoggerFactory` but expects it to be an instance of logback's `LoggerContext`.

In your case, it is an instance of `SimpleLoggerFactory` because `slf4j-simple` appears first in the classpath when you declare the dependency to `dropwizard-core` in the the parent POM: indeed, the `logback-classic` dependency is brought by `dropwizard-core`.

The solution is very simple: you must remove the dependency to `slf4j-simple`.

This is explained at the very beginning of the [slf4j manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved for me after I globally excluded the jar `slf4j-log4j12` by adding the below in my build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group:"org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot exclude library because it is used by another libraries. So, you need to have two implementations. I had such problem so I in my model of Configuration which extends io.dropwizard.Configuration model I override method

```
@Override
public synchronized LoggingFactory getLoggingFactory() {
    return new ExternalLoggingFactory();
}
```